# JQuery remove not removing empty list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the following method to flatten a deep hierarchy of nested lists (I am using TypeScript, but you get the idea for JS).

The method is run against each top level `<li>` element to insert all its descendant `<li>`'s just after itself:

```
    // Flatten a nested list branch - acts in reverse to allow for nested lists
    _flattenBranch(element: HTMLElement)
    {
        var el = $(element);
        $(el.find('li').get().reverse()).each(function ()
        {
            el.after(this);
        });
        // FIX: This is not removing empty descendant lists!
        el.find('ul').remove();
    }
```

I noticed when viewing the generated output I still had empty `<ul></ul>`s under some `<li>`s. What am I missing?

Update (and repro):

### Try this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gu7L/3/

Which results in the following error in the output:

```
<li>Application Form
    <ul>
    </ul>
</li>
```

-
If `Arun P Johny`'s [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3gu7L/1) is called using the following (which is similar to my code) it flattens the hierarchy but fails to remove the child `<ul>`on some elements:

```
$('#test').children('li').each(function(){
    test(this)
});
```

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3gu7L/1/

Comment: can you recreate the issue in the demo

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FXrTX/ if you just pass the ul function ..you should do ideally what Arun did ...

Comment: I am looking into the specific problem now... It appears to only affect certain child lists, so the problem may lay elsewhere. Thanks for the examples though. Nice to know I was not going mad.

Comment: @Arun P Johny: I managed to reproduce the problem, buy substituting my slightly different calling code into your jsfiddle. Why is it working, but not removing all the `<ul>` children if it uses `children()` instead?

Comment: @HiTechMagic I think the dom is actually removed because if you query the dom again it will not return anything see the console http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dUT4n/

Comment: @HiTechMagic because of some crazy reason it is not updating the dom view

Comment: @Arun P Johny: Weird isn't it... Only happens if I use `children()` to iterate the first level `<li>`'s. What is an alternative to iterate the first level of `<li>`'s? (assume my root element is in a variable, so I don't want to query `$('#someid li')`)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple solution, but only if you have 3 level list:

```
function test(element){
    var el = $(element);
    $(el.find('li').get().reverse()).each(function () {
        el.after(this);
        $(this).find('ul').remove();
    });
    // FIX: This is not removing empty descendant lists!
    el.find('ul').remove();
}
$('#test').children('li').each(function(){
    test(this)
});
```

In your example you try find all `<ul>` in childrens of **Home**, but **Application Form** is no longer a child of **Home**.